Extra part for riding mower carburetor , what is this?
My riding mower replacement carburetor came with this extra part , it drops down into a hole perfectly , nothing fell out when I took the original carburetor off . It looks like it might block something if I put it in , I'm worried if I don't it will send gas into the oil ( reason I had to replace carburetor to begin with ) I can't imagine it doing anything but blocking something , does anyone know what this is and whether I should put it in or leave it out ?
Kohler engine KT715-3047 , Craftsman mower T7800 Pro Series
amazon part listed as  :
7000 Series Carburetor for Kohler 1685321-S 22 HP 23HP 24HP 25HP 26 HP Engine Carburetor for Kohler KT725 KT730 KT735 KT740 KT745 Lawn Mower Parts with Air Filter 7000 Series Parts
for


Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does the carb look exactly like the original one you took off? (shape/size/orifices)

Yes it was the correct part , shown is the old one , gaskets did not look right but should be ok .                                                                         Does the carb look exactly like the original one you took off? (shape/size/orifices)

Does this mower have a manual choke?

Does this mower have a manual choke? Choke is up top , high / fast under that , low / slow at the bottom , all one lever

Would you please provide a picture of the "manual choke" on this mower? Use the EDIT link below your question. NOTE: When you answer a question in a comment, please begin your answer with "@"+the name of the person who should receive your answer. This will send the person an alert to read your answer.

@MTA link to choke image https://i.ibb.co/8Kd2vVm/craftsman-mower-choke.jpg

@MichaelR I see. Sorry I have no suggestions.
